# how to configure colors in vagrant ssh bash

Tags: bash, terminal, console, zsh, vagrant

this is the situation:
I have a virtual machine with vagrant, it has ubuntu precise32, I have been installed byobu on it, and byobu tunned the promp.

I have in my host machine macosx, the regular macosx terminal emulator, and have been installed oh my zsh, which changed the shell from bash to zsh, and tunned the colors to a very fancy theme.

well, when i connect to vagrant via ssh, all color configuration disappear, and i suppose it loads the configuration from the ~/.bashrc file in the virtual machine.

how can i change the bright purple colors ? is there any bash theme palette cool to install that you would recommend ?

this is the my terminal [image: byobu console on ubuntu precise32 on vagrant image.]

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> NOTE: I don't know too much about byobu, but I guess it's similar to tmux.

The simplest thing to do is to install `zsh` and `oh-my-zsh` within the vagrant box (suppose you change the default shell by using `chsh` from `bash` to `zsh`). Then when you `vagrant ssh` to the VM, you'll be using `zsh` and see all the fancy stuff.

Not sure how purple is set, whether it is byobu customization or settings in `.bashrc`.

Anyways, if you want to use `bash`, enable 256 color terminal by setting `TERM=xterm-256color`, set the prompt colour as you wish, example [Gist](https://gist.github.com/terrywang/6110232) if you want to use Bash.

Comment: I actually discovered that, in order to see colors when you do some things like 'ls' or 'grep', you need to have dircolors program installed, and then configure the ls in .bashrc as an alias like 'alias ls=ls --color=auto'

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to get colors and a lot of additional features by installing [bash-it](https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it).

It's straightforward to install. The installation takes backup of the current `~.bashrc` and you can always switch back without any risk.